# return a single list property List in Linq

Tags: linq

I am having an issue here i have a list

this.Ddown having 3 properties

i want to write a Linq Query to return one of the property lets say i have property a,b,c

i want to retutn list(c)

how do i do that in linq

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var cList = (from record in this.Ddown
             select record.c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var listOfC = this.Ddown.Select(x => x.c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got this syntaxed right,

```
var listOfC = (from x in this.Ddown
               select x.c).ToList()
```