# Return List<string> after group by

Tags: entity-framework, list, linq, linq-group

I have a function

```
public List<string> UserList()
{
    var q = from i in _dataContext.PageStat group i by new { i.UserName } into ii select new { ii.Key.UserName };
}
```

How can I return `List<string>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [return a single list property List in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835830/return-a-single-list-property-list-in-linq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you just want the distinct set of usernames... why not just use:

```
return _dataContext.PageStat.Select(u => u.UserName)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

If you really want to use grouping, you could do:

```
var q = from i in _dataContext.PageStat
        group i by i.UserName into ii
        select ii.Key;
return q.ToList();
```

You don't need all those anonymous types :)